# Can we write in Microsoft word 2016 with latex commands?

Tags: microsoft-word, latex

I can not install word 2020 or higher versions. Can we write in Microsoft word 2016 with latex commands? Is there a package?

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/is-latex-input-in-word-2016-broken-it-works-in/9f53dff6-c1a2-4f59-a684-e401204aab2d

Comment: spikey Thank you